# can't reset password of signed in user without specific role

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a C# application running in Azure Functions,
I need to change password of a specific user using username\password credentials.

My app using MSAL for authentication (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)

and in order to obtain the ability to authenticate with username\password flow this option is used: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication.

I'm using Graph API for changing the password of the user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

I **do** manage to reset password that way only if I grant the user one of those built-in assign-roles:

Password Admin, Helpdesk Admin, Authentication Admin,   User Admin, Privileged Authentication Admin,    Global Admin

but if I don't give the user one those roles it get the following error message when trying to update the user using PATCH request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/########-####-####-####-########

> Message: {
> "error": {
> "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
> "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2021-04-07T12:56:56",
> "request-id": "########-#####-#####-#####-#####",
> "client-request-id": "########-####-####-####-########"
> }
> }
> }

My problem is that I don't want to give those permission to any user just to change its own password since those roles are too strong.

It doesn't make sense to me that a user can't change its own password with that flow, since with PowerShell it is possible for example with `Update-AzureADSignedInUserPassword` and no special roles needed for the user. Why the role does effect it when I try to do the same operation with my flow.
any ideas how to overcome this problem, what I'm doing wrong or is that even possible in that flow?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Do you want to change your own password?

Comment: Yes I want to change the signed-in user password,
I do have `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permissions.
I tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` and it produce the same problem

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: No I didn't manage to solve it yet, also saw your answer with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword`, do you have any reference to the API? I can't find any

Comment: Still reporting "`Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`" error?

Comment: You shouldn't need to grant any roles to users to use this api. I did a few tests locally and it all worked perfectly.

Comment: The API is currently not documented, but it can definitely solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to run this API via C# so I'm getting 
` "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Unexpected invalid input parameters.",` error now

Comment: Wait a minute, I will write a piece of code for you.

Comment: see my updated the answer.

Comment: Also, make sure you have `User.ReadWrite.All `  delegated permissions.

Comment: hi,  Is there an update?

Comment: Hi, Yes it is working! 
Thank you so much, you can't imagine how much you helped me!

Comment: Can you accept it as an answer?

Comment: already did of course

Comment: Really happy for you, good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to use the `changePassword` endpoint should meet your requirements. You do not need to grant users any administrator roles.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "currentPassword": "Test1234!",
  "newPassword": "Test5678!"
}
```

[image]

---

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var currentPassword = "{currentPassword}";

var newPassword = "{newPassword}";

await graphClient.Me
    .ChangePassword(currentPassword,newPassword)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```