# Microsoft Graph API change user password return an error Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-active-directory

When I tried to change Azure AD user password I keep getting this error: `"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

I added all the permissions that are needed and I user OAuth 2.0 ROPC for authorization. This is authorization request:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("client_id", "clientID");
request.AddParameter("scope", "user.read openid profile offline_access");
request.AddParameter("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
request.AddParameter("username", "userr@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com");
request.AddParameter("password", "xxxxxxxxx");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

This is user update request:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{userId}");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer tokenFromAuthorization");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "\r\n{\r\n      \"passwordProfile\" : {\r\n      \"password\": \"xxxxxxxxxx\",\r\n      \"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn\": false\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Also I tried everything from these two links, but nothing helped:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/9942/do-we-have-any-microsoft-graph-api-to-change-the-p.html
2. ["Update User" operation giving "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.' error in Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56071352/update-user-operation-giving-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operatio)

Permission screen shoot:
[image]

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse the token and provide screenshots.

Comment: What permissions did you grant?

Comment: When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following permission is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

Comment: If you want to change the password of another user, you must be a `user administrator` or a `global administrator`.

Comment: Try it and tell me the result.

Comment: I added permissions screen shoot.

Comment: Are you changing the password for yourself or for other users?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api is wrong, try to change it to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, see: [update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api.  If you use this api to modify user passwords, you must have the role of `user administrator` or `global administrator`.

If you want ordinary user roles to be able to change your own password, then you can use the `/changePassword` endpoint. I have answered [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988170/cant-reset-password-of-signed-in-user-without-specific-role/66996878#66996878) before, and you can use it for your reference.